# Insert Date in Java to Access DB - Weird issue

Tags: java, date, insert

I'm trying to update a table in my AccessDB and i'm having a weird problem.
The update executes without throwing any exceptions but the date value is wrong and 
everytime i update a record the value always changes to "30/12/1899".
Same thing hapens when i'm trying to insert a new record.

In my DB the Date field is in ShortDate format.

Here is an example of my code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);

    if (jList1.isSelectionEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have not selected any computer!");
    } else {
        try {
        String sql = "Update SYSTEMS set "
            + " CPU='" + cpuTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', MOBO='" + moboTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', RAM='" + ramTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', GPU='" + gpuTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', HDD='" + hddTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', PSU='" + psuTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', MONITOR='" + monitorTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', KEYBOARD='" + keyboardTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', MOUSE='" + mouseTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', OS='" + osTextField.getText().trim()
            + "', SOFTWARE='" + othersTextArea.getText().trim()
            + "', PURCHASE_DATE=" + df.format(jDateChooser1.getDate())
            + " where SYSTEM_ID='" + jList1.getSelectedValue().toString() + "'";

        st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated");
    }
    }
```

In order to figure out what is going wrong, I made a button and when pressed i had
a Message showing the result of df.format(jDateChooser1.getDate()) and
it showed the correct date.

```
private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, df.format(jDateChooser1.getDate()));
}
```

I'm using this component to get the date: [JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) If that makes any difference.
I dont mind replacing it with a plain TextField, as long as the date is imported correctly.
When using select to retrieve the date from the DB everything goes well.
The problem only occurs when updating/inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access requires dates to specified in format #MM/dd/yyyy# (including the hash marks).  So if you add the # delimiters at the beginning and end of the date string, it should work.  As maerics suggested, the best would be to use PreparedStatement, because the JDBC drive will handle converting Java Date to the format Access understands, without you needing to format the value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem likely has to do with the formatting of the SQL query; use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of formatting it manually.  Doing so will also decrease the likelihood of errors related to validating user input, including security issues such as [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  For example:

```
String sql = "Update SYSTEMS set "
    + " CPU=?, MOBO=?, RAM=?"
    + //...
    + ", PURCHASE_DATE=?"
    + " where SYSTEM_ID=?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
int nextField = 1;
stmt.setString(nextField++, cpuTextField.getText().trim());
stmt.setString(nextField++, moboTextField.getText().trim());
stmt.setString(nextField++, ramTextField.getText().trim());
// ...
stmt.setDate(nextField++, jDateChooser1.getDate());
stmt.setString(nextField++, jList1.getSelectedValue().toString());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

**[Edit]** Note that the [`PreparedStatement#setDate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29) method requires a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), so you may need to convert the date type returned by your date chooser into one of those, e.g.:

```
stmt.setDate(nextField++,
    new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser1.getDate().getTime()));
```

Comment: I dont know how to do it. Can you give my an example or a link to read?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and i will post back.

Comment: I'm getting an error: no suitable method found for setDate(int,java.util.Date)
stmt.setDate(nextField++, jDateChooser1.getDate());

Comment: @sijoune: double-check the types required by the `setDate()` method and returned by the date chooser `getDate()` method.  Ultimately, I guess it depends on the JDBC driver you're using; see what its documentation says about dates.

Comment: method PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date,Calendar) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method PreparedStatement.setDate(int,java.sql.Date) is not applicable
      (actual argument java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date by method invocation conversion). Should i use java.sql.Date instead. I tried it before and i was getting different dates.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your date format is different from what Access expects. 
To get rid of it, use name parameters - as at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html#supply_values_ps, rather than concatenating the SQL on your own.